# Looking for a seamless way to automate day2 operations

Tags: networking, automation, jinja2

Basically a typical DC environment, there could be multiple spines switches. I'm looking for a way to automate the Day2 operations where I can transfer the load from one spine to other. To do this, I need to configure (or destroy) route-maps / access-list etc. I want this to be seamless, ie there shouldn't be downtime, So I'm thinking of some way to incrementally change the configuration, instead of ripping the whole config and re-configuring.

Think of this like vtysh config (CISCO switch like) of FRRouting.

So basically my switch is configured with some X config and I have Y config, first I find the diff between X and Y and then apply those changes.

During applications and removal the sequence matters, like I can't apply say a route-map when it's not created yet.

Is there any framework available to take adaptation/inspiration ?  OR is there any tool to do this on its own? I think not to re-invent the wheel.

So we have a way to find the diff between the configurations, but re-application part is difficult to understand. The reapplication sequence seems necessary, can't wrap my head around.